# DIY blender lid replacement

Tags: substitutions, equipment, blender

I just got a used Braun MX32 CDN from a thrift store.  It's in great shape.  Unfortunately, it came with a lid from some other model that apparently somebody tried to cut to make it fit.  Naturally, it leaks, but it even leaks if I hold it down as tight as I can.

So, not wanting to spend too much on replacement parts, and preferring not to take it back, I was wondering what my options were for manufacturing my own water-tight lid.  Has anyone had success with this?

Comment: Also, a reusable lid would be preferred.

Answer (score 5):

Any round piece of *something* that's reasonably solid will provide a start for a lid (think, arts and crafts store). Then trace around the top of the blender to see where the top of the container meets the lid. Then glue a foam-rubber gasket (DIY home store... windows) just inside the line and it should create a tight seal between the blender and the lid.

This will provide a makeshift but usable *hold-while-in-use* lid.

Comment: What about the spout?

Comment: My blender's spout is *flush* with the top of the rim. Other's may not be.

Comment: Oh, true (or rather, it's very slightly higher than the rest of the rim)...sorry, I meant, the fact that it's not a circle, how will I find a gasket the same shape?

Comment: The "gasket" I had in mind is a simple strip of foam rubber you bend into an approximate circle. It could flair out a bit to fit the curve of the spout. But it might be *easier* to cover the *entire* surface with some sort of soft rubber, like a thick shelf liner or some such.

Answer (score 2):

Cover with saran wrap and then put a kitchen towel on top of it. The kitchen towel may not be necessary.

Start your blender on the slowest setting, and then increase to desired speed. This will help minimize the splash that you get and decrease the need for a strong tight lid.

Comment: Mmm, yeah, I forgot to mention I had already tried plastic wrap.  It leaked.  I'll try with a towel, though...

Comment: Towel didn't help.  I even tried one of those thick elastic bands you get with broccoli at the store, and after the first few seconds it leaked through the wrap nonetheless.  Thanks anyway, though.

Comment: @Kev, how much stuff are you putting in the blender? You may just need to do smaller batches.

Comment: Yea, I use my blender without a lid pretty regularly.  If you start it slow and do not overfill it, nothing is going to spill out.

Comment: @yossarian, it's not even a quarter full.  @Chris, admittedly, I am testing on the high setting, but that's so I know it will always work...

Comment: @kev, Chris is absolutely right! Start it slow and then increase to high. That will greatly decrease the amount of splash you get (which is why you need a lid).

Comment: @yossarian, it didn't seem to make a difference when I tried just now, since it rapidly pulsates: the power level is going 0,1,0,1,0,1 and then you switch to medium and it's 0,2,0,2,0,2, so you still have the jumps from 0 to 2 (or 0 to 3 on high) no matter what you start with, and that's when it leaks.

Comment: @Kev, bummer. Mine has a perfectly smooth ramp up and a very slow starting speed. Of course, it was an expensive model from a cooking store, so you get what you (overpay) for.

Answer (score 2):

On the random/crazy side, I could almost imagine a partially deflated 4-square/kickball ball or similar rubber ball working.

You deflate it just enough so when you hold it on the top it forms to the shape of the opening.

It's rubber, so easy to wash.

Should be pretty cheap at a local sporting goods store.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend taking the piece that you already have and applying very light, progressive layers of silicone sealant caulking to the edges to snuggie up the fit of the piece you already have.  By progressive I mean put it down light, test it vigorously with dyed water to see where it is leaking, put a little more on those spots until it leaks no more. A tube should set you back about $4 and it's a permanent-temporary solution. The nice thing about this is that, if winter is coming up for you like it is for me you can then use the rest of the tube to draft-proof some windows.

A funnier way of doing this would be to try rubberizing memory foam.

Answer (score 2):

I was searching for solutions for my own blender-with-a-lost-lid.  What ended up working well for me was:  I took a pair of waterproof hiking pants I had in my closet, draped a section of the waterproof garment over the top of the blender, used an elastic headband around the rim, and kept pulling the elastic headband tight as I blended with pulses to make sure it didn't get too out of control.  Not the prettiest way to blend, but it didn't leak.  I was only making margaritas, so I'm sure it'll wash out of that little section of my hiking pants (which don't need to be pristine anyway). Cheers!

Comment: A similar concept might be to use a shower cap with an elastic band.

Answer (score 1):

I have exactly the same problem with the same blender. I had it for 12 years, and I use it every weekday morning to make smoothies. I use a flat lid from a 'disposable' ziplock brand plastic container. Use a lid from any plastic container that's larger than the diameter of the glass blender jar. It must be flat, not ribbed; otherwise, you don't get a seal.